# Does PostreSQL partition table works fast on a large dataaset?

Tags: postgresql

I planning to work with large datasets: >1TB and want to split my data by day (create data partition daily). Now, I want to delete some old data. Will it be fast deleting partition in PostreSQL with such amount of data?

Comment: You would be dropping partitions rather than "deleting". But yes, that's quite fast.

Comment: Relavent documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html